# Google Sheets - using Apps Script to create a pop up based on a specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, popup

I am very new to creating Apps Scripts but am interested in creating a pop-up when a specific item is selected in a cell.

I created a sheet that has a drop-down menu in col K (Supports). I want a pop-up based on what the user selects. I've used a script from a previous person that asked a similar question here but in my script, the pop-up appears no matter what cell I manipulate - even when I delete something from any cell it appears. I only want it to run on col K. Here is the code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //Check if selected cell is in column K (or col #11) was changed to "EL" if not then the pop up will default to Erin
  if(ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 11 & ss.getRange(ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()).getValue() == "EL"){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Send to Ms. Gallagher next.');
    
  } else(ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 11 & ss.getRange(ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()).getValue() == "Sp")
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Send to Ms. Erin Smith next.');

  
}
```

[Here is the link to the file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kASUSXdjYrNcqFJc8W2j-apmvOrqtwd19JfYFxucR5M/edit?usp=sharing):

Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Take full advantage of the [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) function, this will allow you to get the value  of the cell that you're editing, try this:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  //Check if selected cell is in column K (or col #11) was changed to "EL" or "SP" or "Both"
  if(e.range.getColumn() == 11 && (e.value == "EL" || e.value == "Both")){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Send to Ms. Gallagher next.');
  } 
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 11 && (e.value == "SP" || e.value == "Both")){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Send to Ms. Erin Smith next.');
  }
}
```

Note:

- I made some modifications to the conditions, it will now show the notification correctly if "Both" is selected.

Comment: Thank you Bryan! I tried your solution but now I am getting an error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit